# ListView.OnItemClick conflict after animation

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, animation, onclicklistener

Kindly, I have a layout consists of two overlapped layouts, so that when i animate the top layout to the left/right, the bottom layout appears, and I'm  inflating two list-views in the two layouts "top/bottom", and the both lists have a "onItemClicked" listener.

The problem here is when i animate the top layout, and clicked on any item of the bottom layout, i still got the top layout list's listener fired.

I tried to set the top layout list's listener to null after the animation, but, it doesn't work for me.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

when bottom layout appear please set Visibility of top layout is gone or set Enabled false.

Comment: I need it to be partial visible and enabled, so that the user may de-animate the top layout by clicking on it.